# Solidity store storage pointer in storage variable for accessing it from distinct functions

Tags: solidity, contract-development, storage, modifiers

In a contract, using Solidity, is it possible to store a pointer to a storage variable in a storage variable (or somewhere else that may be suitable) and access it from distinct functions?

Consider the following example in Solidity pseudo code:

```
contract AContract {

    struct AStruct { 
      uint a_field;
    }

    AStruct variable_a;
    AStruct variable_b;

    AStruct storage pointer_to_either_a_or_b;

    modifier AModifier()
    {
      if (condition_a)
      {
        pointer_to_either_a_or_b = variable_a;
      }
      else
      {
        pointer_to_either_a_or_b = variable_b;
      }
    }

    function AFunctionUsingPointerToAorB100() internal AModifier()
    {
      pointer_to_either_a_or_b.a_field = 100;          
    }

    function AFunctionUsingPointerToAorB200() internal AModifier()
    {
      pointer_to_either_a_or_b.a_field = 200;          
    }

}
```

Whenever I try to use the "storage" keyword for a storage variable I get the following compilation error for "AStruct storage pointer_to_either_a_or_b":

> Error: Expected identifier, got 'Storage'

Is there a way to circumvent this, like placing the pointer somewhere else in the code?

Comment: State variables are ALWAYS storage variables so you can't add that to AStruct storage pointer_to_either_a_or_b; declaration. It's already a storage variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the keyword storage at `AStruct storage pointer_to_either_a_or_b;` would solve the error (as state variables are always storage ), but you won't be able to achieve what you are trying to do.

The reason is; since `AStruct pointer_to_either_a_or_b;` is a storage variable, assigning a value to it will create an independent copy, not an reference to `variable_a` or `variable_b`.It's mentioned in the solidity docs [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#data-location),

> assignments between storage and memory and **also to a state variable**
>   (**even from other state variables**) always create an independent copy.

I don't know what your actual requirement is, but depending on what you have posted here, I won't use a modifier(and no pointers) but would try something like this,

```
function sample(uint _val) public // val = 100 or 200
 {
      if (condition_a)
      {
        variable_a.a_field = _val;
      }
      else
      {
        variable_b.a_field = _val;
      }
}
```

Hope this helps!

FYI: As I know local variables declared inside modifiers are not accessible inside the function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I suspected it wouldn't be possible to access a shared a pointer to a storage variable within distinct functions.

The actual requirement is having a set of many functions selecting a distinct variable as output, depending on a given condition. I thought of modifiers as a hypothetically good option for creating a pointer to those output variables, but as you stated it's not possible to access variables declared inside modifiers inside functions.

Comment: I will likely have to use something similar to your suggestion, like this, using an additional function to return a pointer:

function Greeter_a(uint _val) public // val = 100 or 200
{
      GetPointer().a_field = _val;
}
(...)
function Greeter_x(uint _val) public // val = 100 or 200
{
      GetPointer().x_field = _val;
}

function GetPointer() public returns (VariableType storage)
 {
      if (condition_a)
      {
        return variable_a;
      }
      else
      {
        return variable_b;
      }
}

Comment: I'm afraid, you can do this with `getPointer()` because the returned value will be a copy of the variable and it won't be pointing to the state variable and modify it

Comment: When adding the "storage" keyword to "returns", it actually does return a reference to the storage variable, like a pointer. So, "returns (VariableType storage)" appears to work.